# Stop Spark batch Job Gracefully

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on the spark job which updates it status in the table about its exectuion, now If the table contains the successful execution already, I need to stop the spark job gracefully.

I tried doing

> System.exit(0)

But the job fails with the

> error :Shutdown hook called before final status was reported.

What is the correct procedure to exit the spark job gracefully.

Comment: This comment I just left on another thread might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580449/spark-jobs-running-on-emr-cluster-system-exit0-used-to-gracefully-completion/50872955?noredirect=1#comment107530077_50872955 . Also, my answer to the question explains a possible reason for the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `sc.stop()` (on the SparkContext) before exiting your application.

See also [similar question on pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236330/kill-spark-job-programmatically/43237995).